# Python xlsxwriter charts: Is there any way to show in legend if series are on primary or secondary axis?

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

If i draw charts with a secondary y axis, it is not possible to see in the legend, if a series is on the primary or the secondary y axis. But thats actually an important information.
I could put a sign like a "*" in the series name, but is there any other way to show if a series is on the primary or secondary axis?

Comment: Is it possible to do this in Excel?

Comment: As far as i know not. I thought i was not the first having this problem and hoped that someone found maybe a nice solution for it.

Comment: Addition: In excel itself i could set the secondary series entries to font style italic to show this, in xlsxwriter it looks like i can only change the font for all entries, not for single ones.

Comment: If it isn't a feature in Excel then I would suggest adding "(secondary)" to the series name, or an asterisk like you suggested.